# User Profile Issues with October 2011 Cumulative Update

Tags: user-profile, cumulative-update

I'm not sure if this is related to the October 2011 Cumulative Update or not, but wanted to see if anyone else was experiencing the same and maybe knew how to fix it.  I installed the Oct CU last week and didn't goto the User Profile Service Application page until today.

Now, none of the User Profile stats are showing up on the page, any ideas?

[image: User Profile Home Page]

Comment: have you kicked off a sync to see if it is working and the stats just need to be reset?

Comment: :( Received a generic error when trying to do that.  Will investigate logs and let you know what I find.

Comment: Getting this error in the ULS logs: Unexpected System.IO.FileLoadException: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)    at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileConfigManager.InitializeIlmClient(String ILMMachineName, Int32 FIMWebClientTimeOut)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-_- all it needed was an IISRESET.  Panicked for nothing.  Thanks Mike for the help.